# Find the chromatic number of the graph below.

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

[image]

I know the chromatic number can't be 2 because there's a cycle of 5 there. I tried 3 but to no avail. So I assume the answer is 4. But I can't prove that it's four and not three. Can someone help out? Thanks.

Comment: The next time you have a question like this, please consider **LABELLING THE VERTICES IN YOUR DIAGRAM**. That will make it easier for people to write answers to your question, and it will make it easier for you to read those answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding notation: Let A be the vertex at the top of the whole thing, and B, C, D, E the other vertices of the outer pentagon, in counter-clockwise order (descent from A to the left on the drawing). Use r, b, g to denote three colors (red, blue, green). I will show that a coloring with three colors is not possible. The proof is by contradiction: assume a coloring with three colors is possible.

Start with the outer pentagon. It must use all three colors as you observed already; and it can't use one color more than twice. (Prove that!) So then the five vertices must use one color once, and the other two colors twice - and those must alternate around the pentagon. For symmetry reasons, we may assume A=r, B=b, C=g, D=b, E=g (with an obvious meaning).

Now let M, N, P be the midpoints of AC, AD and BE. Then M=b, N=g, P=r (Prove!)

Let X and Y be the two vertices at the base of the small triangle inside the whole thing (the midpoints of BD and CE). Continue the reasoning from where I left it off (two more steps, same nature) to show that X and Y must both be r. Which is the desired contradiction.

This also shows the graph can be colored with four colors: at the very end, all you have to do is color Y with the fourth color.

**Added**: As bof shows in his comment below, what I showed above is not a complete proof, because the graph does not have rotational symmetry, it is only symmetric in the vertical axis. So let's fix that.

Let's say the color that is used only once in ABCDE is r. The case B=r is easy; we may assume A=g, E=b, D=g, C=b. Then M=r, P=g, X=b, and the midpoint of PX has no color left for its coloring.

Finally, say C=r and A=g, B=b, D=g, E=b. Then M=b, X=r, Y=g, and then the midpoint of PX must be g, then P=r and finally the midpoint of PY is b. But this is connected to M which is also b, contradiction.

Thank you bof!

Comment: Err... yes, you are correct. I wasn't thinking straight.